# Implicit declaration of CGAffineTransformMakeScale is invalid

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cgaffinetransform

My code used to translate and scale a button used to work. 
Somehow Xcode now throws a warning: `Implicit declaration of function 'CGAffineTransformMakeScale' is invalid in C99.`as well as a semantic issue: `Initializing 'CGAffineTransform' (aka 'struct CGAffineTransform') with an expression of incompatible type 'int'`

What could be wrong with the following code?

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    CGAffineTransform scaleTrans  = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);//This is where both, the warning and error occur.
    CGAffineTransform xTrans  = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(650.0f,0.0f);
    Button.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scaleTrans, xTrans);//combine translation & scale
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code (other than using beginAnimations:context: which has been discouraged since iOS 4). When I dropped it into a method, it gave me no warnings.

Comment: in which method in your view controller you have written this code, and whether you are calling this from somewhere??

Comment: Must be an Xcode bug.

Comment: rishi, this is called after `[super viewDidLoad];` in `-(void) viewDidLoad {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 6 beta 3 fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler can't find where `CGAffineTransformMake` is declared so it thinks that you are creating a new function in the middle of a method (which isn't allowed). Further because it can't find the definition of `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` it assumes that it returns an `int`, not a `CGAffineTransform`. The problem may be that you either don't have the `QuartzCore` framework linked to your project, or you're not importing `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in the file that is using `CAAffineTransformMake`.

Comment: Interestingly, I have `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` already imported and have it linked to the project. I am not surprised this weird issue is happening since my project is being built using Xcode 6 beta 2. I filed a bug report. What baffles me however, is that why does it happen all of a sudden. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: If you're not it may be worth implicitly linking against the CoreGraphics framework as well. This is the framework that actually contains the CGAffineTransform functions. In Xcode 5 it doesn't seem to be necessary to link against this directly though.